# Javascript function not working outside if statement

Tags: javascript

I have 3 functions to simplify question i wrote only code structure without entire code
I'm checking if element is defined using if statement and if elemet exists then function three must be executed but code is not working.

function **three** must be defined only then if **element** exists but it seems i can't define function inside if statement

**error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: three is not defined**

Could you explain what is wrong and why i get **undefined** error?

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('.elem');

async function one() {
  two();
}
one();

async function two() {
  if (elem) {
    three();
  }
}

if (elem) {
  async function three() {
    console.log('works');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">Elem</div>
```

Comment: I do not get the same error? Please can you make sure the example is a [mcve]?

Comment: Why is there an if around the function three? This does not really make sense. And be careful about the async context

Comment: calling a function on a condition makes sense but why the definition?

Comment: The three function only exits in the scope of the if statement, that's why you can't access it inside two.

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: Also, why the `async` keyword? There's no `await` in any of the functions

Comment: "*Could you explain what is wrong and why i get undefined error?*" could you explain why you think  you *wouldn't* get an error?

Comment: `function three must be defined only if element exists` No. It must be _executed_ only if the element exists, that's different.

Comment: Also, this seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In general, you *should not* conditionally have or not have a function. Or a variable or anything else. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Great question.  I think putting the `one()` before the conditional function definition confuses the issue a little bit.

Comment: I don't think everybody is being fair with their "why would you wanna do that?" questions and downvotes.  People paste their whole project into a question, and get told to create a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  Here that is just what the poster has done.  And it's great!

Comment: @Alex028502 "*it's great!*" it's really really not. Having some identifier that might or might not be there is *very bad design*. Having a "conditionally existing function" then should rise further red flags and ring alarm bells and otherwise be a signifier that something is wrong. If the function is meant to be called conditionally, then the declaration doesn't need to be conditional. The other alternative is to always call *something* even if it's a noop. The issue here isn't with the code as much as the whole design that got this code here. See XY problem above.

Comment: Sometimes you just wanna understand how the interpreter works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example how you can make it work using [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

```
const elem = document.querySelector('.elem');

var three;

async function one() {
  two();
}
one();

async function two() {
  if (elem) {
    three();
  }
}

if (elem) {
  three = function() {
    console.log('works');
  }
}
```

now function three will work outside if statement

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, the function is defined in a block and thats why it is not working. You can use a proper IDE which highlights such issues.

Remove the if around the three() function:

See: https://jsfiddle.net/L3pz2mv4/

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('.elem');

async function one() {
  two();
}
one();

async function two() {
  if (elem) {
    three();
  }
}

async function three() {
  console.log('works');
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: You can use Stackoverflow code snippet instead. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355

Comment: No worries, just a reminder. It is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

two changes:

- call `one()` after three has been defined
- declare `three` at the top level, and then redefine it in the condition so that it is accessible everywhere

```
const elem = true;
let three;

async function one() {
  two();
}


async function two() {
  if (elem) {
    three();
  }
}

if (elem) {
  three = async function() {
    console.log('works');
  }
}

one();
```